# Move teamlab from a server to another and got a security error

Tags: security, azure, iis-7.5, iis-8

I have teamlab running very well on a godaddy virtual dedicated server and I am now moving to Azure VM server, I copied all teamlab files to this new server and ran the teamlab service, but when I open the website I get this error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Invalid username
>   or password.
>   [image]

I compared all IIS config on both servers and they are both the same now, what should I check else to run this?

Note old server IIS7.5 new server IIS8